# GSON Ignore missing values from JSON string

Tags: android, gson, realm

I am using GSON in my android app. Currently, I am setting a method that contains a value from my JSON string called "followed". One of items in the JSON string contains followed and the second string does not. I use Realm to persist the unique object so as you can see it just gets overwritten.

Here are 2 json strings to compare as an example:

```
{"customer_case":"OFFICE001","circle_id":"3","address":"10 Canal St","city":"Bristol","state":"PA","zip":"19007","county":"Bucks County","apt_no":"","latitude":"40.1012666","longitude":"-74.855304","profile_picture":"uploads/thumbnails/2014/06/07/16/1402165202_3_16_539356ad9134b3.jpg","id":"539356ad9134b3","google_address":"10 Canal Street","google_city":"Bristol","google_state":"Pennsylvania","verified_zip":"19007","google_county":"Bucks County","status":"Active","add_date":"2014-06-07","circle_name":"Test Portfolio","step":"Rental","loan":"","winterized":null,"boiler":null,"sump_pump":null,"septic":null,"police_id":null,"police":null,"police_phone":null,"electric_id":null,"electric":null,"electric_phone":null,"sewer_id":null,"sewer":null,"sewer_phone":null,"water_id":null,"water":null,"water_phone":null,"fsm_company_id":"5","fsm_company":"Assero Services LLC - FSM","fsm_email":"leemertins@assero24.com","fsm_phone":"2155868317","hoa_id":null,"hoa":null,"hoa_email":null,"hoa_phone":null,"client_id":"9","client":"Test Client","client_email":"krishna162@gmail.com","client_phone":"2157830782","broker_contact_id":null,"broker":null,"broker_email":null,"broker_phone":null,"lawn_contractor":null,"cleaning_contractor":null,"bedroom":null,"bathroom":null,"sqft":null,"lot_size":null,"list_price":"538525","built":null,"assign_date":"06/07/2014","lock_box":null,"gate_code":null,"key_code":null,"property_type":"Unknown","description":null,"sub_status":null,"occupancy_status":null,"street_view":"uploads/2015/06/25/4036/0470e4cd-ce9d-4439-8031-6be5101cd09c.JPG","marketing_front":"uploads/2015/06/25/4036/b099a190-f354-454a-8479-bec67bc41988.JPG","followed":"1"}
{"customer_case":"OFFICE001","circle_id":"3","address":"10 Canal St","city":"Bristol","state":"PA","zip":"19007","county":"Bucks County","apt_no":"","latitude":"40.1012666","longitude":"-74.855304","profile_picture":"uploads/thumbnails/2014/06/07/16/1402165202_3_16_539356ad9134b3.jpg","id":"539356ad9134b3","google_address":"10 Canal Street","google_city":"Bristol","google_state":"Pennsylvania","verified_zip":"19007","google_county":"Bucks County","status":"Active","add_date":"2014-06-07","circle_name":"Test Portfolio","step":"Rental","loan":"","winterized":null,"boiler":null,"sump_pump":null,"septic":null,"police_id":null,"police":null,"police_phone":null,"electric_id":null,"electric":null,"electric_phone":null,"sewer_id":null,"sewer":null,"sewer_phone":null,"water_id":null,"water":null,"water_phone":null,"fsm_company_id":"5","fsm_company":"Assero Services LLC - FSM","fsm_email":"leemertins@assero24.com","fsm_phone":"2155868317","hoa_id":null,"hoa":null,"hoa_email":null,"hoa_phone":null,"client_id":"9","client":"Test Client","client_email":"krishna162@gmail.com","client_phone":"2157830782","broker_contact_id":null,"broker":null,"broker_email":null,"broker_phone":null,"lawn_contractor":null,"cleaning_contractor":null,"bedroom":null,"bathroom":null,"sqft":null,"lot_size":null,"list_price":"538525","built":null,"assign_date":"06/07/2014","lock_box":null,"gate_code":null,"key_code":null,"property_type":"Unknown","description":null,"sub_status":null,"occupancy_status":null,"street_view":"uploads/2015/06/25/4036/0470e4cd-ce9d-4439-8031-6be5101cd09c.JPG","marketing_front":"uploads/2015/06/25/4036/b099a190-f354-454a-8479-bec67bc41988.JPG"}
```

Note the difference is the followed item at the end of the json string.

From the GSON documentation it says:
"While deserialization, a missing entry in JSON results in setting the corresponding field in the object to null."

Is there a way to override this and not automatically set it to null, instead just skip the field?

Here is some code that I am using to deserialize my json:

```
PropertyObject prop = visnetawrap.gsonClient.fromJson(properties.get(i).toString(), PropertyObject.class);

visnetawrap.gsonClient = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class) || f.getDeclaredClass().equals(Drawable.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateDeserializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new TypeAdapter<Double>() {
                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, Double value) throws IOException {
                    if (value == null) {
                        out.nullValue();
                        return;
                    }
                    out.value(value);
                }

                @Override
                public Double read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                        in.nextNull();
                        return null;
                    }
                    String stringValue = in.nextString();
                    try {
                        return Double.valueOf(stringValue);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            })
            .create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may create your own [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

```
public class YourTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<PropertyObject> {

  @Override
  public PropertyObject read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    final PropertyObject obj = new PropertyObject(); //I don't know how is your obj 

    in.beginObject();
    boolean hasFollowedField = false;
    while (in.hasNext()) {

      switch (in.nextName()) {
      case "gate_code": 
        //set value to your obj
        obj.setValue(in.nextString())
        break;
        //do same thing to others...
        //...
      case "followed":
        hasFollowedField = true;
        //set value to obj
        break;
      }
      if (!hasFollowedField) {
        //set followed value to obj what you want
      }
    }
    in.endObject();

    return obj;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(final JsonWriter out, final PropertyObject obj) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject();
    out.name("gate_code").value(gate_code.getGateCode());
    //simple set name and value from obj to JsonWriter
    out.endObject();
  }
}
```

and then register the TypeAdapter to your GsonBuilder obj

hope it would help

Comment: Let me try it and let you know how it works, do I need to do every name or just the followed?

Comment: Damn, I have a lot haha. I will have a chance to try tomorrow, will be back.

Comment: This does not work under my situation. The problem is JSON string one has the same property as JSON string two when grabbing from the server. So when it is missing the field it sets the value but then overwrites the old one when updating the old object. I am using Realm to create or update.

Comment: you need merge JSON obj one and JSON obj two??

Comment: Yes but if followed is null i do not want to overwrite it since there may be a value there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am doing as a work around:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(PropertyObject.class, new JsonDeserializer<PropertyObject>() {
                @Override
                public PropertyObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    PropertyObject prop = new PropertyObject();
                    JsonObject propObj = json.getAsJsonObject();

                    if (propObj.get("id") == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    prop.setPropertyId(propObj.get("id").getAsString());

                    if (propObj.get("followed") == null) {
                        Realm realmThread = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                        PropertyObject existingProp = realmThread.where(PropertyObject.class).equalTo("propertyId", propObj.get("id").getAsString()).findFirst();
                        if (existingProp == null) {
                            prop.setPropertyFollowed(0);
                        }
                        else {
                            prop.setPropertyFollowed(existingProp.getPropertyFollowed());
                        }

                        realmThread.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        prop.setPropertyFollowed(propObj.get("followed").getAsInt());
                    }

                    return prop;
                }
            })
```